# How to split a CSV or JSON file for optimal Snowflake ingestion?

Tags: split, command-line-interface, gzip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake recommends splitting large files before ingesting:

> To optimize the number of parallel operations for a load, we recommend aiming to produce data files roughly 100-250 MB (or larger) in size compressed. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare.html

What's the best way to split my large files, and compress them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the best command line sequence I could come up with:

```sh
cat bigfile.json  | split -C 1000000000 -d -a4 - output_prefix --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

Replace the first step with anything that will output JSON or CSV to stdout, depending on the source file. If it's a plain file `cat` will do, if it's a `.gz` then `gzcat`, if it's a `.zstd` then `unzstd --long=31 -c file.zst`, etc.

Then `split`:

- `-C 1000000000` creates 1GB files, but respects end-lines for row integrity.
- `-d` gives a numeric suffix to each file (I prefer this to the default letters_
- `-a4` makes the numeric suffix length 4 (instead of only 2)
- `-` will read the output from the previous `cat` in the pipeline
- `output_prefix` is the base name for all output files
- `--filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'` compresses the 1GB files on the fly with gzip, so each final file will end up with a size around 100MB.

Snowflake can ingest `.gz` files, so this final compression step will help us moving the files around the network.

Comment: In Windows, this worked in Git Bash rather than the normal command line