# is it possible to efficiently query a subset of data from a huge snowflake staged file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have staged a huge CSV file in Snowflake and find that it takes an enormous amount of time to load it into a table.

We increased the warehouse from ExtraSmall to ExtraLarge but it does not make enough difference.

It's a one-off so we could increase the different timeouts but we do not have admin rights on the account and there is a timeout set at that level.

So I wondered whether we could extract from that staged file in... stages!

I would do several inserts controlling the row_number loaded.

```
INSERT INTO ...(...)
SELECT METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER, DF.$1, DF.$2, DF.$3 
    FROM @LANDING_ZONE.BYM0/DummyFile1.csv.gz DF
    WHERE METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER <= 2;
```

The Select works but it looks like it still goes through the entire file anyway before returning the 2 rows...

Any idea how I could do this more efficiently?

Comment: `We increased the warehouse from ExtraSmall to ExtraLarge but it does not make enough difference.` For CSV files as of the present time (December 2023), only one CPU is going to read that very large CSV file. Increasing WH size on a single CSV file will not help. That may change at some point, but as of now increasing WH size will not help.

Comment: `The Select works but it looks like it still goes through the entire file anyway before returning the 2 rows...` What is the max number of rows that would be required to read? I'm not sure if there's a way, but knowing this may help test some ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not split the csv file into smaller parts? Then Snowflake can load them in parallel

Comment: Or if you just want to query the data, why not create an external table?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I found out that it's still "relatively" quick to read through the file: 17mns for a 32Gbs file. This allowed me to do a MAX(METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER) showing me it's about 84 million (big) rows. We could split the file but it's a lot of work... for a one off exercise. We are not allowed external tables (lots of internal restrictions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake recommends splitting giant CSV files before ingesting them, so they can be read in parallel.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-prepare#file-sizing-best-practices-and-limitations

You should note that this is a Snowflake limitation, and other platforms can read CSVs in parallel. So my hopes are that eventually Snowflake won't have this limitation (and I'm asking for this inside the company).

In the meantime, please split your gigantic files before ingesting into Snowflake. For example, using the CLI:

```
cat bigfile.json  | split -C 1000000000 -d -a4 - output_prefix --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz'
```

[How to split a CSV or JSON file for optimal Snowflake ingestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718175/how-to-split-a-csv-or-json-file-for-optimal-snowflake-ingestion)

Now, there's an extra caveat in your question: It seems the original file is .gz compressed (`DummyFile1.csv.gz`). That means most other platforms will have the same problem nevertheless, as that's a `gzip` limitation.